# Is it possible to catch the instruction that wrote an invalid value into the pc register?

Tags: linux, arm, segmentation-fault

After an instruction, for example,

```
pop {pc}
```

writes an invalid value, say 0, into the `pc` register, CPU will try to fetch the instruction located at 0, which will usually trigger a segment fault.

While handling the fault, we can read the values of the registers, including that of the `pc` register, which is 0 in this case. Obviously, if we could learn the address of the instruction that caused the invalid `pc` value, like the address of the `pop` instruction above, it would help us a lot more with debugging. Is there a way to catch the fault a teeny bit earlier (catch the previous instruction, which caused the fault)?

Comment: Use an in-circuit-emulator with trace capability.

Comment: Arguably, this is a question better suited for stackoverflow (and I generally propose the other way around). Basic premise: the instruction is not invalid when it is fetched - it is invalid when the processor attempts to execute it. And even though the fetch-decode-execute model is pretty far from what a modern ARM pipeline looks like, the fact that the two are distinctly separate operations remains.

Comment: Just use a debugger, there must be about a zillion out there.